# add menu item value as a class to ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I display a list of players as follows, but I'd like to add the name of the player as a class to the `ng-view` element when the user clicks on a player's name, to view their details via a route. How could I do this?

```
  <tr ng-repeat="player in playersList">
     <td>
         <a href="#/details/{{player.id)}}">
            {{player.name}}
          </a>
     </td>
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="" ng-view></div>
```

**Contoller:**

```
.controller('playersController', function($scope, footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.playersList = [];


  footballdataAPIservice.getPlayers().success(function (response) {
        //Dig into the response to get the relevant data
        $scope.playersList = response;
    });
```

Comment: show your full markup please

Comment: ok I added my controller to the OP

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in the controller for that route you can access the players name?

Just place a data-binding on the `ng-view` for it's class. Also, within your controller for players, add a value to `$rootScope` for player name.

```
<div class="{{ playerName }}" ng-view />
```

Your controller:

```
$rootScope.playerName = player.name;
```

Comment: will that pick up the one they click on automatically?

Comment: If you have that `$rootScope.playerName` in your controller (when that route gets loaded) it should!

Comment: ok I added my controller to the OP, can you check please, thanks for your help!